# T4MVC problems with MVC 2 under VS2010: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult'

Tags: .net, t4mvc

Just added the T4MVC templates to my project, built and then tried to use the cool new features it introduces.

I tried to update `RedirectToAction("NotFound", "Error");`

to `RedirectToAction(MVC.Error.NotFound);`

I get the following error at build:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult'
```

Also, in my views, when I try to do something like this: `<%= Url.Action(MVC.Home.Index) %>`

I get messages that say:

> argument type 'method group' is not
>   assignable to parameter type
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult'

Not really sure where to begin troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call it like the action method.  e.g. MVC.Error.NotFound().  See the [doc](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC_doc&referringTitle=T4MVC) for more examples.

Comment: Wow, guess I was having a blond moment! I'm not at a place where I can test this... will update this question later. Thanks for the super fast response.

Comment: It's actually a common mistake when first using it, because it feels a little strange to call a method.  Needless to say, it's not actually calling your action.  But it looks like it!

Comment: I really appreciate your support.

Comment: This is genius, T4MVC is plain awesome. Thank you for making this.